# Multiple rows in variable for error-handling using throw

Tags: t-sql, variables, error-handling, throw

If some data validation rules are violated I am able to raise an simply error using THROW:

```sql
IF EXISTS
    (SELECT 'Martin'
    )
THROW 50000,'Data exists',1;
```

If I want to know exactly the string I can use variable like this:

```sql
SELECT * INTO #mko_temp from
(SELECT 'martin' AS name,
        45 AS age
UNION all
SELECT 'honza' AS name,
        25 AS age
UNION all
SELECT 'Petr' AS name,
        30 AS age) a
;
DECLARE @ErrMsg NVARCHAR(500)
IF EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT T.name   
    FROM #mko_temp AS T
    WHERE T.name NOT IN ('martin', 'honza')
    ) 
BEGIN
    SET @ErrMsg = (SELECT T.name    
    FROM #mko_temp AS T
    WHERE T.name NOT IN ('martin', 'honza'))
    DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(2048) = FORMATMESSAGE('Invalid value in column Name = %s',@ErrMsg);   
THROW 50000,@msg,1;
END
```

Result:

> Invalid value in column Name = Petr

But if I change the rule ..... `WHERE T.name NOT IN ('Petr')` I get an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Am I able somehow build an error log for multiple rows?
Result like this:

> Invalid value in column Name = honza
> Invalid value in column Name = martin
> ....

Comment: I would suggest, instead, using string aggregation and then you can return *all* the values in a single error (assuming that the error can't go over 4,000 characters).

Comment: Unfortunetaly I have mssql 2016 where STRING_AGG is not supported

Comment: Then use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) method. String aggregation is still able to be achieved in SQL Server 2016 and earlier; there's just no built-in function for it.

Comment: something like that seems usable, thank you for advice
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF(
        (SELECT
       ', ' + name
       FROM #mko_temp
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.','varchar(max)')
        ,1,2, ''
     ) AS [Message]
    FROM #mko_temp